# No virtual method functionname(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I) jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing this error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method function name(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Landroidx/compose/runtime/Composer;I)V in class Lcom/class name; or its super classes (declaration of 'class_name' appears in /data/data/package_name/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex)

I am trying to access some function from separate module which i added as a dependency in my app gradle file. The function is accessible inside app module but the error is occurring during compilation of the app.

App Module level build.gradle.kts file:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta02")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32")
    }
```

Project level build.gradle.kts file:

```
buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion= "1.0.0-beta07"
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Danish. I am also facing the same issue. Can you please share your solution? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some version conflict.

Update your **Android Studio** to **Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Beta 3**

Check your project level **build.gradle** file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta03"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
}
```

Then set your **compose** version: **'1.0.0-beta07'**

I think it will solve your problem.